Microsoft Partner Center API: HTTP 400 Authorization header token missing user information
I want to use the Microsoft Partner Center API but Im unable to test the scenario described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/create-earnings-export-request
Where Im getting HTTP 400 with a quite generic error message: Authorization header token missing user information
My current workflow:

obtain access token using client_secret
using https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant}}/oauth2/token

client_id:<CLIENT_ID>
client_secret:<CLIENT_ID_SECRET>
grant_type:client_credentials
resource:https://api.partner.microsoft.com


query https://api.partner.microsoft.com/v1.0/payouts/transactionhistory using the access token obtained in the previous step.
Thank you for your help in advance.

